Failed to create collection item - Unsupported file type
I've set up a simple API integreation which is meant to "create live items" on a collection with a set of values.
For example, this collection is blog posts and each item has two require props:
name (single line text)
blog_post_body (rich text field)
The weird issue im now having, is that for some of the API calls it works, and for others it doesnt, all apparently related to URLs I provided for the  elements I submit in the API call.
The error I'm getting on the attempted creation is: Unsupported file type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
In other cases where it works, I successfully get the item id (and can confirm on the webflow + website it works)
For example, this will work (for the blog_post_body param):
HELLO WORLD

But this wont work:
HELLO WORLD

The only thing i changed was the image source URL, and so it does indeed look to be impacting it. I'm just not sure what's wrong with my hosted image (i also tried cloudflare, not only gcp/firebase).
This is the API endpoint im using on Webflow btw - https://docs.developers.webflow.com/reference/create-item-live
Anyhow.. error is super weird and no info on this on the doc.. so came to the reddit angels and hoping for your help.
Thank you!
